# U.K. transit visa to go to Antigua and Barbuda from Uganda

Tags: visas, uk, antigua-and-barbuda

On 15 January 2020 i applied a U.K. direct airside transit visa to pass through the UK on my way or route to Antigua and Barbuda  and my visa was rejected and give reason that i don't qualify for that visa because am from a country or territory entity specified in schedule 1 to the immigration  (passenger  transit visa) order 2014 (as amended). Such persons seeking to pass through the United kingdom en route to another country or territory without entering the United kingdom require a transit visa.
So i really don't know where i went wrong because i have a invitation from a family friend from Antigua and Barbuda and his paying for my trip and i provided everything so at end rejected and given reason i don't understand and Ugandans a visa free to Antigua and Barbuda

---

[image][image][image][image][image]

That's my letter of refusal.
Am Ugandan citizen and am using Ugandan passport and i submitted my landtitle,my bank statement,my marriage certificate, my business certificate and my TIN Number, my sponsor bio copy of is Antigua and Barbuda passport, his company or business certificate, my life insurance,yellow card,copy of my national ID and my wife National Identity Card copy, Invitation letter to Antigua and Barbuda and i applied direct airside transit visa but they said i don't qualify for that visa.

Comment: Much more information is needed. For example: Are you a foreign resident of another country? If so, what country? If you have any other transit points in your itinerary, where are they and at what point in the trip? What time and day do you arrive in the UK? What time and day do you depart from the UK? Do you have to change airports in the UK? If you are to use the same airport, do you have to change terminals? Do you have checked baggage? What information did you submit to UKVI in support of your visa application? Please attach a scan of the refusal letter (with personal details blanked out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You applied for a [UK Direct Airside Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/direct-airside-transit-visa). Your application was denied for the reason stated in the refusal letter: you are a national of a country (Uganda) whose citizens cannot use a Direct Airside Transit Visa to transit the UK.

You should instead have applied for a [UK Visitor in Transit Visa](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa/visitor-in-transit-visa).

Although their names are similar, these two types of visas are not the same. The applications and requirements are different.

Comment: Okay thanks for that wonderful interpretation of that refusal decision. But in my application i submitted my land title(house papers), a letter from my employee, certificate of good contact,marriage certificate, my own business certificate and my TIN number from revenue, Invitation letter from my friend from Antigua and Barbuda, his business certificates, my bank statement,Bio copy of is Antigua and Barbuda passport, yellow book for yellow fever, and my business transactions. So please my question is what did i miss to submit because i want to submit or apply again UK transit visa  next week

Comment: Maybe you didn't miss anything, maybe your included everything necessary and your visa would have been granted if you'd applied for the correct visa. In this case, however, you applied for the wrong visa and were refused because you were not eligible to receive that visa. Unfortunately, you must start again from the beginning and apply for a UK Visitor in Transit Visa.

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I read the [order](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2014/2702/made) and could not get that interpretation out of it. It explicitly defines a transit passenger as someone not entering the UK. The DATV is the correct transit visa; the Visitor in transit visa is for those who want to clear immigration and transit landside (e.g. changing airports). It looks like the ECO made a mistake.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. All the Order says is that the OP needs a visa. We don't know what information was presented to the examining officer about the proposed transit, and thus don't know if DATV or TITV is correct. Different tickets or airlines result in having to pass Immigration to collect luggage, or a transit >24 hours or a change of airport, would all disqualify a DATV. The brevity of the refusal letter suggests this sort of underlying disqualification, rather than a fuzzier "we don't believe you" type of denial.

Comment: Thanks for the advice so am gonna apply for UK visitor in transit visa next week that's what am gonna do and see what happens

Comment: hello everyone its david

Comment: on 15/01/2020 I applied for a direct airside visa to the UK on my way to Antigua and Barbuda and it was refused and still, I applied again on 17/02/2020 a visitor in transit visa to the UK to my way to Antigua and Barbuda but what surprised me is they gave me the same reasons they gave me last time that I applied for direct airside visa yet I applied for visitor in transit visa so am wondering if really UKVI reads our applications so please any advice why step must I take.